# How to put .iso file to USB?

Tags: 11.10, usb, iso, usb-creator

I want to try out Linux Mint. I am on Ubuntu 11.10 now. How can I mount .iso file on USB? And also, will my other files disappear in USB when I mount it? Thank you.

Comment: Are you having a bootable Ubuntu 11.10 USB drive? Do you simply want to copy the .iso file or you want to make it **dual-boot** Ubuntu 11.10 nd Linux Mint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also try [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) which should install the .iso and everything up for you.

(Although like the previous answer, your other files will be wiped)

Comment: Actually once Unetbootin finishes making the Live USB you can put back any random files you had and the Live USB will still boot.

Comment: @UriHerrera That goes for any other method (with, sometimes, the exception of `dd`).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to create a Linux install disk (on USB) is to use the '**Startup Disk Creator**" application.

Just click on Dash icon (top left), and type <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> (then click on icon).

[image]

**Note:** *This will overwrite (and erase) any files already on the USB drive.*  You should use a spare USB stick of 2GB or 4GB capacity.

Comment: Is the `Startup Disk Creator` software related with *Create a LiveCD*? I don't think so.

Comment: Yes. This does perform that function. *It is the preferred method from within **Ubuntu**.*

Comment: Oh, I interpreted the `SDC` as the `Startup Applications`, I didn't see the second icon. Another thing, this work with Ubuntu `ISOs` *only*, but you say that this could work with a derived OS (Xubuntu-Lubuntu, or **Mint**, etc) ?

Comment: I have used for custom kiosk builds of 10.04 LTS. *It loads the ISO content (unchanged) to target USB, and adds a bootloader. There is an issue with compatibly between the kernel in bootloader and the install (LiveCD). However, that is the same 'kernel' as for Debian, RedHat, etc. as well.* For **Mint** (current) it should be fine ..

Comment: Your right, is the same kernel. Is great to know that. And thanks for your time and information!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your files will disappear from your USB because you are reformatting your drive. I'm sure Linux Mint has instructions for installing there ISO on to the USB, but it'll be more hands on.

[Here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/389) is a how-to that should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

**MultiSystem** enables a LiveUSB to do everything, ideal for exploring different Linux distributions do not install them on your PC, and it seamlessly, Or to install the Linux distribution of your choice on your PC much faster than via a LiveCD with the speed of USB 2.0 ports.

Essential throughout the current range of netbooks that do not have CD.

Ideal for all, anyone doing maintenance, your USB key with you and ready for use in a mobile home your friends in a cafe ...

See the current list of [Linux distributions](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/os) supported by MultiSystem.

Primary interface that allows drag / drop files iso.

Manually add the repository to your sources.list file, then the key, reload your sources, then install the package multisystem.

```
# # Add the repository of MultiSystem
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot all hands'
# # Add the public key
http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot/multisystem.asc wget-q-O-| sudo apt-key add -
# # Reload the sources
sudo apt-get update
# # Install MultiSystem
sudo apt-get install multisystem
# After installing multisystem add your $ USER group adm.
sudo usermod-a-G adm "$ SUDO_USER"
```