# How to create a OS X Mountain Lion Bootable USB drive on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, usb, mac, macosx, usb-creator

I already know how to do it on Mac OS X (plenty of instructions online).

But is it possible to do it on Ubuntu? If yes, how?

Comment: I think that your solution (Question and answer) already exist in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/83184/62483).

Comment: @Lucio Unfortunately, no. This post tells about .iso image files, but I have .dmg image file, which is different.

Comment: Oh, now I understand you. Your right, the Mac images are `.dmg`. I hope that my answer can be useful for you. If it does, just let me know.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you want to create a LiveUSB you need a `.iso` image to make it. The Mac image is a `.dmg` file, so you **must to convert this file** into `.iso`, and then install it.

## Install DMG2IMG

DMG2IMG <sup>([1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DMG2IMG), [2](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dmg2img.1.html))</sup> will convert the `.dmg` image into a `.iso` image.  To install open a terminal and enter this command: `sudo apt-get install dmg2img`

## Convert the Image

With `dmg2img` you will create an `.img` file and this file will have the [same format](http://mikebeach.org/2011/08/28/converting-a-mac-dmg-image-to-iso-in-ubuntu/) as an `.iso` file, you just need to replace the extension.

In the terminal enter the following commands or paste the script with the necessary modifications:

```bash
# Replace "OriginalFile.dmg" with the filename including the extension
# of your file. The extension will be replaced where necessary unless
# you want to specify the filenames yourself.

filename="OriginalFile.dmg"

# Replace with your file name and it will create the IMG file
dmg2img -i "${filename}" -o "${filename%.dmg}.img"

# Note that the extension of the first file is ".img"!
mv "${filename%.dmg}.img" "${filename%.dmg}.iso"
```

## Make the LiveUSB with an ISO image

Now you already have the `.iso` image, with which you will make the LiveUSB. Several tools and answers exist to help you create bootable USB drives, [some](https://askubuntu.com/q/83184/62483) are specific to PC/MBR booting (Bootcamp) where Macs and newer PCs since Windows 8 require/support UEFI booting.

A related question: AskDifferent – [Official way to obtain an OS X ISO file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/128319/130733)

Answer (score 3):

why not just `dd` the `.img` file after conversion?

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/orig.img of=/dev/s**
```

Comment: Since you asked, `dd` is a good program if a bit hard to understand for some, however `dd` has one major drawback compared to GUI USB creator applications . Sometimes when you `dd` an .img file onto a USB drive you can't reformat it if you want to reuse the USB drive. The GUI live USB programs don't have this problem.

Comment: @karel actually you could use a software like SDFormatter with `FORMAT SIZE ADJUSTMENT = ON` to restore the true capacity of USB drive (after dd'ing USB drive could appear as e.g. 50 MB instead of 4GB and standard built-in OS software sometimes can't restore it)

Comment: @JakeBadlands I downloaded SDFormatter  to try it, but ClamAV reported a malware threat on the file that I downloaded, so I'm sticking to my tried and true method which uses programs from the Ubuntu Software Center: http://askubuntu.com/questions/496309/how-to-unboot-my-bootable-usb/496328#496328

Comment: It should be possible to use `parted` to recreate the partition table on a `dd`'d USB stick. It makes sense to me that some GUI tools don't support recreating the partition table and thus are stuck with whatever size was put there when `dd`ing, but it would seem strange if it couldn't be done with parted, is this known not to work on any USB stick?