# How to download Ubuntu to a USB for another computer?

Tags: live-usb, data-recovery, macbook

I have an Asus F5VL that was running Vista but when I tried downloading Office 2010 the OS crashed. Now I need a recovery disk to get it back to life but I only have a macbook available to me to download anything and this has no disk capability.

I would like to give Ubuntu a try but I am wondering is it possible for me to download Ubuntu on my Macbook to my USB *without affecting the Macbook* and then upload to my Asus F5vl?

Comment: I think that they are several question where you can find the necessary information. Anyway, I'll create an answer recompiling it.

Comment: Also, in this site we don't say "thanks" in every phrase. We want to help you, and we have [tools to reward a nice gesture](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2260/62483).

Comment: If you found that the any answer worked, you can aceppt it so other users can find it more easily.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the [Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and download the version that you want to. I recommend you Ubuntu 12.04. *After that you will have an ISO file.*

You need to [put the ISO file in your USB stick from your mac](https://askubuntu.com/a/225835/62483). *Now you have a USB flash drive where you can boot Ubuntu.*

All that you have to do is configure your BIOS to boot from the USB stick, save your changes, plug it and reboot. Now you can choice the *Try Ubuntu* option and do what you want to. And if you like it, you can easily [install it erasing Windows Vista](https://askubuntu.com/q/48838/62483) or trying [other options too](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328/62483).

**NOTE**: *your mac system will not be harmed*, because you are using it to download a file and install it into a USB flash drive. So you are not modifying any there.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but when I hit boot from usb on the boot screen it comes up with "invalid system disk, replace the disk and press any key". Do I need to make the USB bootable or anything, all I have on it is the Ubuntu ISO.

Comment: You need to use Unetbootin or a similar software  to make a bootable USB from the ISO, and then write the ISO to that USB, to ensure that it works.  Unetbootin exists for Mac.  If you do this, and run into a similar issue again, try redownloading the ISO file, then recreate the USB from that newly downloaded ISO, then try to boot from the USB.