# My pendrive size decreased from 32GB to 2.25MB after booting it with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

I wanted to try Ubuntu. I downloaded the iso file from the ubuntu site. Then made my 32GB pendrive bootable with it. After that it is showing that my pendrive size is only 2.25MB. And there was no file in it. I've formatted it. But it is not working.

Comment: Try the answer to this question, it might work: [How to unboot my bootable usb](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496309/how-to-unboot-my-bootable-usb). From the question: *I formatted my pendrive once, but the size of the pendrive still shows 2.25 MB, whereas this is an 8GB pendrive. How can I get rid of this problem?* Your pendrive size is also showing only 2.25MB.

Answer (score -1):

see this video in this link give below to retain the full capacity of the pendrive
https://youtu.be/_TRWUJ1oZHc

Comment: Please do not use links as answers. Post the relevant steps to answer the question.