# Not recognising Flash Drive

Tags: usb-drive

I'm trying to create a bootable USB for Kali Linux. When I plug my USB in it recognises it in disks, but I'm not able to format or anything. Here is a picture:

[image: screenshot of Disks]

EDIT: I am not having trouble with uploading the ISO file and making the USB a bootable USB, I am having trouble because Ubuntu won't properly recognise the USB drive.

This is what I get when I launch startup disk creator [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdNd4.png).

Comment: I have got the latest version of ubuntu so i believe 19.04 and I tried used disks to create it

Comment: Disks does not create bootable USB. It helps you manage internal and external disks and partitions. You need "Startup Disk Creator" or another app like `mkusb` or `BalenaEtcher`.

Comment: I used the restore disk image and selected the iso file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal)

Comment: This is not a question on how to create a bootable usb, it's about what to do to get the usb to be recognised

Comment: @Barty200YT Thanks--sorry about the [tag:iso] tag, which may not apply here. It looks to me like the USB drive just doesn't have any partitions on it (or doesn't have a usable partition table), but if that's not the case or you don't think it explains what you're seeing, then I recommend running `dmesg` before and after plugging it in; the lines that are new after you plugged it in may make useful additions to your question.

Comment: How do you add partions

Comment: Yes about a million times

Comment: @Barty 200YT The ISO writing software will overwrite any existing partition and create what it needs. https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal contains instructions on how to use dd to write to any device, with or without existing partitions. If it fails, the USB flash drive has died without question.

Comment: @Barty200YT, If you still have problems, I suggest that you analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky, get a working USB boot drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore original size and unboot my bootable USB pendrive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496309/how-to-restore-original-size-and-unboot-my-bootable-usb-pendrive)

Answer (score 0):

[Disks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man1/gnome-disks.1.html) [has a way to do it](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-disk-images-using-gnome-disk/), with its *--restore-disk-image* option; once you have created a LiveUSB ISO image, you can replay it onto a USB Flash Drive to create a LiveUSB.  From its GUI, pick the USB drive on the left panel. Then choose *Restore Disk Image...* from the drop-down **≡** menu. Many thanks to [user68186](https://askubuntu.com/users/68186/user68186) for that development!

The preferred method per Ubuntu Tutorials https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 has explicit step by step instructions using [Startup Disk Creator](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/disco/+source/usb-creator) to create a LiveUSB from an ISO file.  In step 4, instead of selecting the Ubuntu ISO file, use your other ISO file.

If your USB flash drive is rejected by Startup Disk Creator, then it is failing or has a bad connection. Make sure to plug the flash drive into a socket on the PC, not through a cable or hub.

If it still fails, follow the instructions in [How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal) or use a different USB drive.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: My usb isn't connected through a hub and has a good connection and i don't have any other usb sticks with enough memory

Comment: It's not because it worked yesterday and i used it to install ubuntu on my computer

Comment: The `--restore-disk-image` option of `gnome-disks` allows creation of Live USB from ISO files. So based on the man page you linked in the answer, you **can** create a Live USB with Disks. I just tried it. It does create a Live (bootable) USB.

Comment: @user68186 What was the command you used in Terminal?  How did you specify the flash drive as the target for the ISO file?

Comment: I didn't use the command line option, though I see that it is available based on the man page. I used the Disks GUI. Selected the USB drive on the left panel. Then chose **Restore Disk Image...** from the drop-down ≡ menu.