# Dead USB after accidental unplug

Tags: partitioning, usb

I tried to install Ubuntu on my new USB flash drive, but I accidentally unplugged the USB flash drive during formatting filesystem and now it says `NO MEDIUM` and 0 bytes. I tried to align drive letter, but it opens many windows with `Please insert a disc into USB Drive (D:)`.
DiskPart says: `Virtual Disk Service error: There is no media in the device`.
Ubuntu detects my usb and says no partition table. When i try to make new table in ubuntu via gparted, it freezes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello. Are you trying this on Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: @karel yes, ubuuntu detects my usb, and says no partition table. When i try to make new table in ubuntu via gparted, it freezes.

Comment: @David, hello. Im trying on both of these.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore original size and unboot my bootable USB pendrive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496309/how-to-restore-original-size-and-unboot-my-bootable-usb-pendrive)

Comment: @karel I dont want to unboot... i accidentally unpluged my usb during formating file-system.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I dont want to unboot... i accidentally unpluged my usb during formating file-system.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't have everything and you have misunderstood the link, but I am assuming that you still want to recover the use of the physical USB and then reformat it and boot from it again after you have successfully recovered it.

Comment: @karel, i undestand the link, but my USB says No media. I think it has a broken partition table

Comment: The link explains how to fix a broken partition table.

Comment: @karel USB is not showing in FDISK list. 