# Ubuntu encryption during installation

Tags: encryption, gparted, luks, cryptsetup, decryption

For the first time while installing Ubuntu 23.04 I clicked the button for encryption. For bad luck the installation got stuck, so now I have an encrypted Lenovo laptop and I can't decrypt mmcblk0 even though I know the passphrase. I have try to decrypt it, but with no result.

Results of `lsblk` :

[image: lsblk]

Answer (score 2):

Boot from the Ubuntu 23.04 live USB that you used to install Ubuntu, and select the *Try Ubuntu* option to start an Ubuntu live session. Launch the built-in GParted partition editor, and reformat `/dev/sdb` as FAT32 in order to remove the LUKS encryption. Then you can reinstall Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: With gparted don't let me format , also decrypt option is grey letters and can't press I LL send a photo from gparted

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/496328/) is stronger than GParted, and it also can be run from an Ubuntu live session.