# How to make an install USB for Windows on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows

That's basically it. I have a Windows 7 .iso but I don't actually have a DVD at the moment so I was wondering if it was possible to make a Live USB using something like "Startup Disk Creator" and put the .iso onto my 16GB USB. If not, what's the best way to burn it to a DVD and I'll buy some tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: The StartupDiskCreator is not intended for use with Windows ISOs. As for burning to a DVD, just burn as image, there is no best or worst way. Good luck.

Comment: @captainjamie If you were to link to and/or include a summary of how to do this *on Windows*, then this might be more likely to be considered on-topic. I'm not sure this is really off-topic, but it would be more clearly on-topic if it were explicitly asking how to perform some Windows-related action on Ubuntu, rather than asking *what Windows-related action to perform*. If this does get closed, I recommend asking on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) (but search there first, of course). If you don't know how to make a Windows 7 bootable USB using any OS, Super User is probably a better place.

Comment: What? I have no idea how to do this on Windows. I don't even have a Windows install... My question has nothing to do with Windows apart from the fact that the .iso I happen to want to put onto a USB contains the Windows operating system. @mikewhatever, I'm aware the StartupDiskCreator is not intended for Windows, that's why I asked for something like it. If it worked, I would have used it.

I don't see how this is off-topic. It's a question about how to make an install USB using Ubuntu, and this is an Ubuntu forum! How is that off topic?

Answer (score 1):

An internet search suggests this: http://www.kczon.com/linux-ubuntu-bootable-usb-windows-7-8/

In short, what you need to do is the following:

1. Format USB drive as NTFS
2. Install Unetbootin for Linux
3. Use Unetbootin to make a bootable usb from the iso

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if there is some software in Ubuntu other than WinUSB can take this job, since WinUSB cannot install in some Ubuntu 13.04. If your version of Ubuntu is upto 12.10, WinUSB is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try winUSB 
http://en.congelli.eu/prog_info_winusb.html

why you want to use windows ;) http://crmda.ku.edu/computing/Linux:PersonalEvolutionOfAWindowsUser

Answer (score 0):

I use Multisystem. Not sure how this will work for windows, but looks like can accept any ISO.

**Edit**: Multiboot page on http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/ can help you and the homepage is in french here: http://liveusb.info/

**Edit**: Here you will find the installation steps: ([How to put .iso file to USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83184/how-to-put-iso-file-to-usb/83217#83217))

Comment: Hi Dee! Can you please at least provide a link to this "Multisystem" and how to install it?